# How to reduce repeated strapi api calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strapi

I have the following code

```
  const getData = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const { page, pageSize } = pageOption

    try {
      setShowContentLoader(true)
      const { data: isActiveData } = await axiosStrapi.get('/changelog-sellers?isActive=true&_sort=id:DESC')
      const { data: pageOptionRows } = await axiosStrapi.get(`/changelog-sellers?_start=${(page - 1) * pageSize}&_limit=${pageSize}&_sort=id:DESC`)
      const { data: rows } = await axiosStrapi.get(`/changelog-sellers?type=${type}&_start=${(page - 1) * pageSize}&_limit=${pageSize}&_sort=id:DESC`)
      const { data: oldRows } = await axiosStrapi.get('/changelog-sellers?_start=0&_limit=10&_sort=id:DESC')

      setFeaturedPosts(isActiveData.slice(0, 3))
      setOldChangelogSellers(oldRows)

      if (type === 'all') {
        const { data: count } = await axiosStrapi.get('/changelog-sellers/count')

        setTotal(count)
        setChangelogSellers(pageOptionRows)
      } else {
        const { data: tabTitleCount } = await axiosStrapi.get(`/changelog-sellers/count?type=${type}`)

        setTotal(tabTitleCount)
        setChangelogSellers(rows)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error)
    } finally {
      setShowContentLoader(false)
    }
  }
```

I am repeatedly calling `/changelog-sellers` to get different kinds of data. Is there a way to simplify my code so that I only call `/changelog-sellers` once? Or is it impossible because I need to pass different parameters to each of the different api call even though they are all sourced from `/changelog-sellers`?

Comment: It looks more like a backend design issue. If your backend API is able to handle multi values and not only certain partials of the query parameters. I would just append all the path variables to one request, which returns all the corresponding data in one JSON. There you should be able to access it via JSON property.

Comment: @BurakAyyildiz So there is no way to reduce api calls from the frontend when passing different parameters when they all come from the same source?

Comment: no. As your backend accepts only a certain order of parameters. That's why you should change the behaviour of your backend, which accepts more parameters, so your backend can handle more then one business logic. But return still one json.